# ModelState Nested Collection Validation

Tags: c#, angularjs, validation, asp.net-core

Got an issue trying to map AngularJS UI to validation returned from .NET Core API Controllers.

AngularJS is used as the UI interface for our internally built API, and one of the end points allows us to initialise a complex type. This type has multiple nested objects, and we would prefer to allow a single API call to add this item to the database. However, during validation of the items going into the system we get a valid validation return, just have no idea how we can parse this to work with the client side code.

**Example code:**

*ViewModelA*

```
public class ViewModelA 
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

*ViewModelB*

```
public class ViewModelB 
{
    public ICollection<ViewModelA> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public IActionResult Post(ViewModelB vm) 
{
    // Omitted validation processing

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Omitted
}
```

*AngularJS Application View*

```
<div ng-repeat="x in values.fooList track by $index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="{{$index}}_foo" ng-model="x.foo"/>
        <span><!-- Validation Here --></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If we get a validation error in the above post action on an item within the collection we get something along the lines of:

```
{
    "Bar[0].Foo" : "Error Message",
    "Bar[1].Foo" : "Error Message"
}
```

We can't utilise Angular's model system since the returned JSON has no concept that the error is within a list of items. An idea I had to traverse these errors messages would be using jQuery to process the outputted html, but if we are using AngularJS this seems wrong. Is there any other way this could be handled?

**Note;** We are using MVC to return the views for the AngularJS application, if that helps to generate relevant answers.

Comment: You should normalize your error response to an atomar object. Like `{
    errors: [
        {
            fieldId: 0,
            message: "Error Message"
        },
        {
            fieldId: 1,
            message: "Error Message"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @lin This doesn't help. A sub list I can create, but how would I traverse the errors for dynamic collection of items?